# Undef predefined agent configuration parameter in TeamCity

Tags: build, parameters, teamcity, agent

How can I hide (or undef) some predefined agent configuration parameters in TeamCity build agent?

For example, agent detected the presence of Visual Studio 2010 and created two predefined parameters: VS2010 and VS2010_Path.

If I explicitly specify these parameters in conf/buildAgent.properties with empty values, they would be still exist. Is there any way to totally undef them (except uninstalling Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 0):

To remove/change TeamCity Agent parameters, you have to remove/change in database tables.
you might have MSSQL, MYSQL or other database.

check the table called `agent_type_param`

or you will find all parameters by

```
SELECT * FROM agent_type_param
```

This table contains below columns :

```
[agent_type_id]
,[param_kind]
,[param_name]
,[param_value]
```

Remove entry from table or null value of "param_value".

Comment: I tried to remove these entries from table, but no changes were made in agent Configuration Parameters page. I assumed that an agent reboot is needed, and after reboot all these entries came back to DB. It seems they are automatically generated each time an agent starts. So I think the only way to undef them is to uninstall VS